# Activity that does not obstruct clicks

Tags: android, themes, android-dialog

I am starting an activity that is themed as **Theme.Dialog**.

I was wondering if it is possible to display the activity and still be able to click everything behind it. I know this is possible in android but I don't know how to do it.

An example of that is the volume pop up that shows up when you try to increase or decrease the volume settings on android 2.0. If you try to click on it all clicks are registered on whatever activity is running behind it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know this is possible in android but i don't know how to do it.

It is not possible.

> An example of that is the volume pop up that shows up when you try to increase or decrease the volume settings on android 2.0. If you try to click on it all clicks are registered on whatever activity is running behind it.

That is a `Toast`, not an `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. What type of views can i use with the toast? Is there any possibility of having a listview that autoscrolls for example since a toast will never receive focus as stated in the documentation.

Comment: @Mak: "What type of views can i use with the toast?" -- I have no idea, but since it will not receive any input, I suppose only non-interactive ones will work. "Is there any possibility of having a listview that autoscrolls for example since a toast will never receive focus as stated in the documentation." -- I'll be surprised if you can get this to work. I'll be even more surprised if you can get this to work and not confuse the heck out of the user. But, sure, there is a possibility you can get this to work.

Comment: Thx again. You definitely have a point that it might be very confusing to the user. I will try to rethink my approach